# ViewModel вывод максимальной и минимальной цены во View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Не могу реализовать, вывод максимально и минимальной цены во View

Вот так выглядит ViewModel

```
public class OzonViewModel
{
    public static IQueryable<ozon> ozon { get; set; }


    public int minPrice = (int)ozon.OrderBy(c => c.price).First().price;
    public int maxPrice = (int)ozon.OrderByDescending(c => c.price).First().price;
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> illustration { get; set; }


    public OzonViewModel(IQueryable<ozon> _ozon)
    {
        ozon = _ozon;
    }

}
```

Контроллер выглядит так

```
private BooksEntities dc = new BooksEntities();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {


            var o = (from a in dc.ozon select a);
            ViewBag.Illustration = new SelectList(o.Select(y => y.illustration).Distinct().OrderBy(y => y).ToList(), "illustration");



            var fo = new OzonViewModel(o);
            return View(fo);
        }
```

Во View все выглядит так

```
    @model Phoenix.Books.Models.OzonViewModel
<div class="col-sm-2">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.illustration, ViewBag.Year as SelectList, "Год", new { @class = "form-control input-sm", @id = "year" })
                </div>
         <div class="box-content">
                                    <b class="tag-title">Цена</b>
                                    <hr />
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" id="from_price" placeholder="От @Model.minPrice" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" id="to_price" placeholder="До @Model.maxPrice" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Почему-то не работает. Как мне решить эту задачу?

Comment: Все таки выводят 0? Что это значит не работает?

Comment: Пишет ,что значение не может быть не определенным

Answer (score 3, accepted):

при создании   `var fo = new OzonViewModel(o);`   ozon еще не получил значение, вам надо изменить код

```
public class OzonViewModel
    {
        public static IQueryable<ozon> ozon { get; set; }


        public int minPrice = 0;
        public int maxPrice = 0;
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> illustration { get; set; }


        public OzonViewModel(IQueryable<ozon> _ozon)
        {
            ozon = _ozon;
            minPrice = (int)ozon.OrderBy(c => c.price).First().price;
            maxPrice = (int)ozon.OrderByDescending(c => c.price).First().price;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Спасибо все работает!

Answer (score 1):

У вас коллекция не содержит еще элементов, а вы уже обращаетесь к ней. Метод `First` на пустой коллекции будет выдавать ошибку, потому что Вы пытаетесь получить доступ к элементу, которого нет. Добавьте обращение после инициализации значениями, например в конструктор

```
public class OzonViewModel
{
    public static IQueryable<ozon> ozon { get; set; }

    public int minPrice = 0, maxPrice = 0;
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> illustration { get; set; }

    public OzonViewModel(IQueryable<ozon> _ozon)
    {
        ozon = _ozon;
        minPrice = (int)ozon.OrderBy(c => c.price).First().price;
        maxPrice = (int)ozon.OrderByDescending(c => c.price).First().price;
    }
}
```

И для нахождения минимального и максимального элементов, не обязательно сортировать последовательность, можно воспользоваться методами `Min` и `Max` из `LINQ to Object`

```
minPrice = (int)ozon.Min(c => c.price);
maxPrice = (int)ozon.Max(c => c.price);
```